# Возможно ли получить бесплатный матчмейкинг от Gamesparks и как это сделать?

Tags: разработка-игр, gameserver

Имею игру и давно хотел сделать возможность сетевой игры. Начал писать свой back-end, но понял, что нюансов слишком много и всех их я осилить не смогу. Тогда я и нашел сервис Gamesparks. В сети было написано, что для инди студий и студентов бесплатный доступ к их мультиплееру, но они сменили ценовую политику с 19 февраля 2019 года и толком информации я не нашел. Подскажите: возможно ли получить доступ к бесплатному матчмейкингу и как это сделать, или, если такой возможности нет, подскажите альтернативы.

Comment: Этот вопрос наверно стоит задать не неизвестным людям (большинство которых впервые слышат про этот продукт), а самой компании, которая знает как у них все устроено, вам так не кажется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой возможности нет. Не хочу оставлять открытый вопрос.